# loading images into UICollectionView and caching issue

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uicollectionview

I have filled the collectionView with images from an API and cached it.
It works but there is a issue when images load initially. The imageView occupies some other image from the collectionView cache for a fraction of second but it is detectable and looks odd
instead i would like to keep it empty until it loads.

```
AF.request(imageurlstring).responseImage { response in

            if case .success(let image) = response.result {
                self.image = image
                imageChache.setObject(image, forKey: NSString(string: urlString))
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the imageview's image to `nil` or a placeholder in `prepareForReuse` method of the collection view cell class.

Comment: Yeah @TonyNguyen , I tried. it did reduce the problem to some extent but still it is sometimes showing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because collection view reuses the cells and image download requests are being queued. That's why for some cells you get this multiple setting of images.
To avoid the multiple setting you can save the url of the image somewhere inside the cell. And check if it match the url of a response.

```
 cellImageURL = imageurlstring 
 AF.request(imageurlstring).responseImage { response in

       if case  .success(let image) = response.result
          if cellImageURL == response.request.url {
             self.image = image
          }
          imageChache.setObject(image, forKey: NSString(string: urlString))
       }
 }
```

Comment: it had its own problem now the cells are not refreshed unless i scroll down and then scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting any new image make the image as nil. So add self.image = nil before following line:
 self.image = image